# Multiplying two columns of same table and storing result to the third column of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, product

I m having a table

```
SALES(sno,comp_name,quantity,costperunit,totalcost)
```

After supplying the `costperunit` values, `totalcost` need to be calculated as `"totalcost=quantity*costperunit".`

I want to multiply `'quantity'` and `'costperunit'` columns and store the result in `'totalcost'` column of same table.

I have tried this:

```
insert into SALES(totalcost) select quantity*costperunit as res from SALES
```

But It failed!

Somebody please help me in achieving this..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: as a best practice, do not store the attributes that can be calculated/derived

Comment: do not store the column totalcost as it can be derived from the other two columns, quantity and costperunit

Comment: why you are supplying your values identically ?

Comment: @rags : I need to generate a report where total cost need to be displayed thats y am keeping it stored.!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try updating the table

```
UPDATE SALES SET totalcost=quantity*costperunit
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use update.

```
UPDATE SALES SET totalcost=quantity*costperunit
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you do not calculate this field manually but make it a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead - so it calculates automatically for you.

You can change the column with following query:

```
ALTER TABLE Sales
DROP COLUMN totalcost

ALTER TABLE Sales
ADD totalcost AS quantity*costperunit
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/edaa0/1)**

Comment: @RavitejA Not much more to add, if you run that ALTER your `totalcost` will from now on always automatically show as product of `quantity*costperunit`. It will not store own values, but calculate on the fly whenever you select it. Also you will not be able to change it's values manually anymore. If unsure, try with new column.

Comment: @RavitejA Check the edited version. Apparently `ALTER COLUMN` can't work with computed columns. You need to drop it and create again.

Answer (score 1):

try this while inserting new row

```
      INSERT INTO test(sno,comp_name,quantity,costperunit,totalcost)
      Values (1,@comp_name,@quantity,@costperunit,@quantity*@costperunit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Best not to store fields that can be calculated, but if you want to, with SQL Server you can set a field to be calculated automatically when values are there.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server Management Studio there will be a column attribute while creating or modifying a table called "Computed Column Specification" under "Table Designer" (it can be done in code but this is easier).  You can put expressions in there such as [quantity]*[costperunit], and the field will be always automatically evaluated against that expression - meaning you never have to do the manual calculation.

Comment: Just hit the up arrow on my original answer, marks it as useful