# Adding two values from selected query in c#

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error in pasring this code.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda5 = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into [bodega].[dbo].[Stocks] ([Itemlookupcode],[Quantity],[Status],[Description],[Amount],[Total]) values ('" + ilc1.Text + "','" + qty1.Text + "','IN','" + description.Text + "','" + amount.Text + "','" + int.Parse(amount.Text) * qty1.Text + "')", con);
```

It throws the following error:

> Error 1   Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'   G:\Data\Payroll\Program\BodegaItems\BodegaItems\Form1.cs    26  268 BodegaItems

I tried

```
'" + Convert.ToInt32(amount.Text) * qty1.Text + "'
```

but it did not work out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `int.Parse(qty1.Text)`?

Comment: It wont give an error if corrected this one with 

`'" + Convert.ToInt32(amount.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(qty1.Text) + "'`

But error after i insert on query

Comment: Mabuhay! Sir @RobLang thanks it also works well but after I insert the query heres what ive got.

`Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: What is that error?

Comment: Can you try building the SQL Query into a string first and seeing what the result of that is?

Comment: Don't wrap Int/Decimal Type values into Single quotes while inserting

Comment: Mabuhay! Sir @JaydipJ do you mean 

`"+ int.Parse(amount.Text) * int.Parse(qty1.Text) +" `

Comment: Or is it best solution not to insert values from computation and let the datagridview compute that two values after it was inserted on table?

Comment: @astroboy Yes do similar for other columns as well, single quotes are use only for string type data

Comment: Thanks Sir @JaydipJ i read it also here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696928/multiplying-two-columns-of-same-table-and-storing-result-to-the-third-column-of)

Comment: Your code is subject to sql injection. **Never** build sql query by concatenating user input. If the user enter sql language reserved caracters, it will breaks the query. Especially a malicous user can inject any arbitrary sql command using this technic. To overcome this issue, it's higlhy encouraged to use SqlCommand and SqlParameters (using `@param1` syntax in the command) to let the sql provider handle the proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

The bug is telling you that it can't multiply an integer `int.Parse(amount.Text)` with the text value of `qty1.Text`.

You need to parse `qty1.Text` into an `int`: `int.Parse(qty1.Text)`.